# menu using clickable images?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a menu using clickable images, but they don't seem to be working? I was following a tutorial and it uses something like

```
Intent biodata = new Intent(mainActivity.this, profile.class);
```

but it's not working so I tried to look for something else and someone said to use v.getContext() instad of ....this

it works on my other page but it doesn't work on this page?

mainActivity.java

```
package skripsi.garden;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public ImageButton buttonBio;

    public void init(){
        buttonBio= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonBio);
        buttonBio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             Intent biodata = new     Intent(v.getContext(), profile.class);

                                             startActivity(biodata);
                                         }
                                     }


        );
    }

    public ImageButton buttonList;

    public void tombollist(){
        buttonList=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
        buttonList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                              Intent listTaman = new Intent(v.getContext(), gardenlist.class);

                                              startActivity(listTaman);
                                          }
                                      }


        );
    }

    public ImageButton buttonWeather;

    public void tombolcuaca(){
        buttonWeather=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonWeather);
        buttonWeather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onClick(View v) {
                                                 Intent cuaca = new Intent(v.getContext(), weather.class);

                                                 startActivity(cuaca);
                                             }
                                         }
        );
    }
}
```

and this is the xml
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/foliagemain"
    tools:context="skripsi.garden.mainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/selamatdatang"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBio"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonbiodata"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonList"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonWeather" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonList"
        android:src="@drawable/buttondaftartaman"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonHelp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonhelp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonBio"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonBio" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:src="@drawable/buttoncuaca"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your buttons in your onCreate method.  They do not need to be in their own method.

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ImageButton buttonBio;
    public ImageButton buttonList;
    public ImageButton buttonWeather;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        buttonBio= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBio);
        buttonBio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent biodata = new Intent(mainActivity.this, profile.class);
                startActivity(biodata);
            }
        });

        buttonList=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonList);
        buttonList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent listTaman = new Intent(mainActivity.this, gardenlist.class);
                startActivity(listTaman);
            }
        });

        buttonWeather=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonWeather);
        buttonWeather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cuaca = new Intent(mainActivity.this, weather.class);
                startActivity(cuaca);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it gave me this log 
/Users/lilies/AndroidStudioProjects/Garden/app/src/main/java/skripsi/garden/mainActivity.java
Error:(59, 1) error: class, interface, or enum expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Reformatted it for you and added one missing bracket.  If it won't compile, you should be able to go through the code and see if there is a missing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call your methods `init()`, `tombollist()` and `tombolcuaca()` in `onCreate` method of your activity after setting the layout.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
        tombollist();
        tombolcuaca()
    }
```

This would initialise the button to do the action written inside the `onClick`.

If the methods are not called, the button would not be initialised and hence the click will not work.

You could also use `android:clickable="true"` in your imageButtons, and then assign the click function `init()` to the button in your layout xml.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonBio"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonbiodata"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonList"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonWeather"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="init"/>
```

Then you wouldn't need to initialise the buttons in your activity. On click of the button, the method would be called.